# Where can I get clarification about source code licences?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, licensing

I have used Stack Overflow a lot, but its only related to code and programming. I've used only a few Stack Exchange sites.

I've not found any question that is about licences. There are so many pieces of code which are copyrighted. I want to ask questions about such topics. I would like to get the details in Question Answer format rather than searching for licence and then going through the whole document.

Is there some site where I can ask about these licences in a question and answer format?

Or can I even ask questions about licences on any Stack Exchange site?

Is going through the licences the only way to know about terms and conditions?.

Just an example where it could also help. An issue i faced in 1 case (Question is not about broken link):

```
 * Copyright (c) 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * You may not modify, use, reproduce, or distribute this software
 * except in compliance with the terms of the license at:
 * http://developer.sun.com/berkeley_license.html
```

This is written in a few programs and if I click that link mentioned it redirects to **http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.htm** instead of showing the terms and conditions.

Comment: There is no Stack Exchange site that I know of that is suitable for this type of questions. One reason is that legal advice on the Internet is such a hot potato, and there are so many things that can go wrong with it.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for http://choosealicense.com/ ?

Comment: Generaly if a link is broken, google may be of some help. You can find it [here](https://java.net/projects/javaeetutorial/pages/BerkeleyLicense) or use http://web.archive.org to see a page back in time.

Comment: Ya, i can find it in other links. But my idea of the question was to get the terms and conditions in a question and answer format.

Comment: @TejusP I hope it can help other wondering, but for the question itself, Pekka's comment is right, and the answer below too. There's too much possible friction and too few objectivity on this kind of questions.

Comment: Software licensing questions are specifically on topic at [programmers.se].  As in, it's listed in the tour (ping @pekka).  Asking why a link is broken is absolutely not on topic, as the only people who can answer that is the people who control the link.  As for distinctions about what kind of licensing questions are acceptable, that's a question for their meta.  If you are concerned ask there first.

Comment: @Will : try to understand the question. and read my previous comment. "But my idea of the question was to get the terms and conditions in a question and answer format". i meant it for any licence. not just that link. i never asked why the link is broken. it was an example.

Comment: *"I want to ask questions about such topics. For example [example here] This is written in a few programs and if I click that link mentioned it redirects to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.htm instead of showing the terms and conditions."* Try to understand why someone would think you *might* ask about a broken link.  People do it every day, so forgive me if I mentioned it.

Comment: @Will: no problem. not an issue. People down voted my question by misunderstanding it. so i've made an edit to the question. I don't expect down votes when the question is not so horrible.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240883/172661

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the number of people who are experts on source code licenses and would be willing to answer questions about them on a StackExchange site is so low that the proposed site would get no answers, which would make it useless.

Or, worse, it would get *plenty* of answers from crazy people who think they're lawyers, people with an axe to grind against some particular license, etc., which would make it *worse* than useless.

From what I understand, in many jurisdictions, an actual lawyer who answers might be opening herself up to serious liability. Or at least many lawyers seem to claim that's true.

There may be a few people who are licensing experts without being lawyers (maybe because they work for the Open Source Initiative or ChooseALicense or something), or who are lawyers in jurisdictions where they can get away with it (maybe because there's a clear and simple way to make it clear that "this is true to the best of my knowledge but it's still not legal advice that I can be held liable for"), but my guess is there won't be enough to sustain the site.

Comment: I can't downvote my own answer, but… as [Will](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will) points out, [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) specifically says that questions about licenses are on topic there. So, my guess that no SE site would want to cover such questions seems to be both wrong and irrelevant. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of the awesome site [Open Source SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com)? `</end-of-blatant-advertising>`

Open Source allows questions for the nitpicking of many licenses. If you want the community to recommend a license, they're fine with that too :)